# How can host magento at example.com/path/to/magento?

Tags: magento2, nginx

this kind is a simple question still I'm struggling to figure out how to achieve this.

I have a landing page, and if the user clicks to enter a certain section I want him to see the store (located at `/magento`).

When I'm installing magento through the command line there's a baseURL argument, what I should put in there? My intuition is it should be `example.com/magento`, but I get errors.

Maybe I'm not configuring nginx properly. Here's my super simple config:

```
server {
    listen                      80 default_server;
    listen                      443 default_server ssl;

    ssl_certificate             /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key         /etc/nginx/ssl/key.pem;

    client_max_body_size        10M;

    root /var/www/html;

    location ./magento {
            index index.php;
    }
}
```

I tried using baseURL as `example.com` and `example.com/magento`, I also tried removing the `location ./magento...` from nginx. I will get either 404 or 403.

Any ideas on how tho achieve this goal? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First try to setup the Magento properly and the try to set the `location` directive if needed.

All the Magento related files and directories should be there in the `/var/www/html/magento` directory.

1. Run the line to create a new virtual host for your Magento site:

`sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/magento`

2. add the following in the above file

   ```
    upstream fastcgi_backend {
         //If php 7.0
         server  unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
         //If php 7.2
         //server  unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    server {
         listen 80;     
         //Change the below example.com with your domain
         server_name www.example.com;   
         //Change the below paths if necessary  
         set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html/magento;  
         //Change/Create the directory if it is other than below one(magento)
         include /var/www/html/magento/nginx.conf.sample;
     }
   ```

**NOTE:** You can keep `listen` and `ssl` related syntax as it.

3. Activate host by creating a symlink:

> ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/magento /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

4. Verify the server configuration

> nginx -t

5. If successful, the following message displays:

> nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

6. Run the command to restart nginx:

> systemctl restart nginx

[**Refer below official Magento guide for more information**](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/nginx.html)